# why is my if else not working?

Tags: c++, c, if-statement, for-loop

I got a nice little function with a 2D array. I want to search for the income in the first array and then use that same int to find the right number in the 2D array.

I have limited my problem down to one line of code. The if Else statement is not working inside the for loop. I don't know why. Any ideas that isn't hitting it with a hammer.

```
   float get_total_income( float income)
{
    char status[10];
    float over_income = 30001;
    float final_rate = .35;
    float adjusted_income = 0;
    int check = -1;
    int x = 0;
    float rate;
    float array_income[] = { 6000.00, 9000.00, 15000.00, 21000.00, 25000.00, 30000.00 };

    float rates[][6] = { { .028, .075, .096, .135, .155, .174 }, { 0.0, .052, .083, .122, .146, .163 }, 
    { .023, .072, .089, .131, .152, .172 }, { 0.0, .038, .074, .110, .138, .154 } };


    printf("\n\t YOUR INCOME AFTER DEPENDANTS: %.2f", income);


    while (check < 0)
    {
        printf("\n\n\nEnter your Status (S, MJ, MS, SH)");
        gets_s(status);

        if (status[0] == 'S' && status[1] == '\0')
        {
            single_total = single_total + 1;
            check = 0;          
        }
        else if (status[0] == 'M' && status[1] == 'J')
        {
            mj_total = mj_total + 1;
            check = 1;
        }
        else if (status[0] == 'M' && status[1] == 'S')
        {
            ms_total = ms_total + 1;
            check = 2;          
        }
        else if (status[0] == 'S' && status[1] == 'H')
        {
            sh_total = sh_total + 1;
            check = 3;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n\n INCORRECT STATUS. Enter (S, MJ, MS, or SH) \n\n");
        }
    }


    if (income > over_income)
    {
        rate = final_rate;
    }
    else
    {
        for (x = 0; x<6; x++)
        {
            printf("num %i# \n", x);

            if (income <= array_income[x])
            {
                rate = rates[check][x];
                printf("\t\nworks, %i# in loop answer: %.3f\n",x, rate);
            }
        }//end for loop
    }//end if

    printf("\n\t YOUR TAX RATE: %.3f", rate);

    return rate;
}
```

In this part:

```
for (x = 0; x<6; x++)
            {
                printf("num %i# \n", x);

                if (income <= array_income[x])
                {
                    rate = rates[check][x];
                    printf("\t\nworks, %i# in loop answer: %.3f\n",x, rate);
                }
```

Instead of stopping to one time to print it is printing the entire table. 
For some reason the If statement has no power here and the compiler is ignoring it.

What should happen is 
IF income = 2000 and <= the income_array
it should print whatever that part of the array is. 
However it just keeps going like the conditions are always true.

Comment: Where is `over_income` declared? And what is it's value?

Comment: Hold on i totaly forgot to add the actual output. My bad.

Comment: Also, please specify exactly what you are expecting and what happens instead. "is not working" is not very specific..

Comment: `The if Else statement is not working inside the for loop` there is no else in for loop.

Comment: `int check = 0;` It does not enter the loop. `gets_s` needs size.

Comment: Sorry guys hold on before u go nuts on me. I need to redo my post here. I forgot major details here.

Comment: OMer Obaid - already on it. forgot to add that too. (blood sugar is low)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are never breaking in your loop, so it will always run to the end. If you want to stop iterating as soon as the condition is true, use the following code:

```
for (x = 0; x<6; x++)
{
    printf("num %i# \n", x);

    if (income <= array_income[x])
    {
        rate = rates[check][x];
        printf("\t\nworks, %i# in loop answer: %.3f\n",x, rate);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes but if the conditions are true then it should only print one time.

Comment: Well, which `printf` are you referring to? Unless you insert a `break` into the `if`-statement's body, the loop will always run to the end regardless of the condition. So the first `printf` will always run 6 times.

Comment: @user3255517 you are not breaking if `if`  condition is true and not even changing the values

Comment: how would i break if the condition is true?

Answer (score 3):

The loop condition should be `while (check == 0)`, otherwise the loop is never entered because you initialized `check` to 0

Comment: @user3255517 the loop is not even entered. How can that work?

Comment: I changed it somehow. Sorry for the confusion you where right.

Answer (score 1):

Since the income values is passed from another function I cannot guess, what is should be

My suggestion would be printf both the values before if statement `**income** and **array_income[x]**`
and find out the root cause.

And also, You expect `if (income <= array_income[x])` should run only one time, but by looking into the array-income values there are possibilities your income value should always be less.